# Runtime basic auth with SimpleHttpOperator in an Airflow DAG- How to supply a HTTPBasicAuth to auth_type

Tags: airflow

I want to use Basic Auth with a SimpleHttpOperator, where I specify the credentials at run-time. I tried constructing the header myself, but it seems to be getting trashed/overidden by the connection or something. Docs say SimpleHttpOperator auth_type accepts a requests.auth.AuthBase, but when I try to provide one as follows:

```
    launch_backup_pipeline_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id="get_task",
        http_conn_id="my_conn",
        method="GET",
        endpoint="my/url",
        auth_type=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'),
        log_response=True,
    )
```

I get:

```
TypeError: HTTPBasicAuth.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'r'
```

This is basically not documented at all by Airflow and I have found absolutely no examples.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% certain but looking at the HttpOperator source the auth_type parameter is expecting just the type of the object not the object itself.
If you need to pass in the credentials in the request call, you can use the PythonOperator with a callable function that does requests.get

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/http/operators/http.html#HttpOperator

```
    :param auth_type: The auth type for the service
..
        auth_type: type[AuthBase] | None = None,
```